# Conflict Lint + Typescript React 18 / 'React' must be in scope when using JSX

Tags: typescript, react-tsx

I'm studying react 18 + typescript, and I have a problem. I have this code that has a problem. React import is not being used. But when I remove this import, in the return line it says "React must be in scope when using JSX". How can I remove that error?

What is the best way to create the component? I could use React.FC and stop the error but it doesn't seem like the best solution

Obs: I know I can disable this rule in eslintrc, but I would like to better understand the error and resolve it in the correct way

```
import React from 'react'

type TweetProps = {
  text: string;
};

function Tweet(props: TweetProps) {
  const { text } = props; //error in here if i remove import
   //React must be in scope when using JSX

  return <p>{text}</p>;
}

export default Tweet;
```

Comment: Try `import * as React from "react"` instead.

Comment: @CRice 
Now all the hooks I use I use with React.hook ?